# IE8: intense flickering for Flash in Windows 7 RTM

Tags: windows-7, flash, internet-explorer-8

Whenever I view a page with Flash on it (example [www.fox.com](http://www.fox.com)), if I move my mouse around the page flickers *intensely* - like siezure inducing flicker. Is this a known issue, and is there a way to fix it?

- Windows 7 RTM x64
- IE8
- Flash Player, Acrobat Reader, Shockwave Player are all I installed
- Consistent across 3 very different machines (AMD ZM-82 + Radeon HD3200 laptop, Core i7 + NVidia GT220 desktop, P4D + NVidia 6400GT desktop), but all with the above software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem with flash on 32-bit IE 8 in Windows 7 64-bit. Check [this](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/GettingReadyforWindows7/thread/c04085a0-4b0f-4aa8-802f-a9f5a058d062) forum post for more information.

Some suggestions (which 280Z28 disagrees with):

- Moving to 32-bit will fix the problem, but you will miss out on some of the [Advantages of 64-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit#Pros_and_cons).
- If you don't mind changing browsers that should also fix the issue.

Comment: Adobe never ceases to disappoint.

Comment: At some point it has to get old having Adobe make people change which Microsoft products they use because they can't get a single plugin working right year after neverending year. A more appropriate suggestion would be disable Flash due to their sorely lacking platform portability - as causing *major* stability and security issues with the most popular browser for the better part of a decade can't possibly count as supporting it.

Comment: so true ... almost a year ago, they had THIS to say: "Adobe is working on Flash Player support for 64-bit platforms as part of our ongoing commitment to the cross-platform compatibility of Flash Player. We expect to provide native support for 64-bit platforms in an upcoming release of Flash Player following Flash Player 10." ongoing commitment my foot :)

Comment: That upcoming release is scheduled for 2064? Maybe the want a memorable date, or something like that...

Comment: If you add "(which 280Z28 disagrees with)" after "Some suggestions", I'll mark this as the answer. :)

Comment: as   you   wish

Comment: It's not that I think they're incorrect because they are technically correct statements - I just don't like calling them "suggestions" on how to deal with an Adobe problem.

Comment: @alex ADOBE: 64bit computing remains in its infancy as long as it pleases us! :) those who think Microsoft is evil 'ain't seen nothing yet'. Adobe bought Macromedia for the sole purpose of getting their hands on the format, not because of Macromedia's (rather mediocre) product range. and certainly not to dump money into development. Adobe Systems, Inc. has always been about formats (and thus strangleholds), not about advanced technology and if they hadn't struck that fateful deal with the Knoll brothers, Adobe wouldn't be worth mentioning today. :)

Answer (score 1):

Went to the AMD site and downloaded and installed the ATI driver through the Catalyst Software Suite, replacing the HP ATI driver that came with the laptop.  Rebooted and flicker is gone and screen is clearer and brighter as well.  Link to AMD is http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx

Comment: Updating video drivers for my Intel GMA 4500MHD seemed to do the trick, too (Lenovo X301 w/ retail Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

moving to 32bit does not fix the problem. i run on 32 bit windows 7 and it flickers like hell

Answer (score 0):

It seems inconsistent. Sometimes it does flicker, sometimes it does not, and it changes from boot to boot. It is annoying, and doesn't appear when using Firefox 3. My theory is that IE8 was developed to be a 64-bit browser, so the 32-bit is an emulation that does not play too nicely with other 32 bit applications. Firefox is natively 32-bit so 32-bit Flash works just fine. I think Adobe really need to get their finger out and smell the 64-bit processors. Failing this, they will lose out to open-source alternatives.